# assertHistorySize() for State or MutableState in Android Test

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing, mutablestateof

I am used to use awaitValue + assertHistorySize to test how much a LiveData has received and what it has got.
So I write the following code (only as an example):

```
val dataObserver = viewModel.data().test()
viewModel.setCurrentButtonFilter(DataType.AllData)
dataObserver.awaitValue(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).assertHistorySize(2)
```

With viewModel.data() I will get the LiveData. Everything is okay.

And now with Jetpack Compose I just start to use MutableState instead of MutableLiveData and State instead of LiveData. But I still wanna use something like assertHistorySize to test how many time the State has changed. Is there something cool to do this?

Thank you.

I am trying:

`stateObserver..assertHistorySize(2)`

But you know it doesn't exist :)